# Writing to a windows network share from a docker container

Tags: docker

I want to write a file, from a linux based docker container, across the network to some shared folder on a windows server.

Some detail : I have a python script that writes a file to some network share ( say \\FS001\shared\log\results.txt). This script gets containerized with a linux based container.

How to configure the container (perhaps map a volume?) so that the script can continue to write files to that share? I am ok with making changes in the actual script as to the location of the file. for example, I can change \\FS001\shared\log\results.txt to /data/results.txt.

Comment: Imagine a colleague sent you an email with exactly what you wrote here. Would you be able to fire off a response with an answer, or would you have some clarifying questions?

Comment: @dfundako more detail added. better?

Comment: I've got a feeling that you're not entirely familiar with Linux? Windows paths use backslashes, but a native Linux path would be `/data/results.txt`.

Comment: @MSalters - fixed

Comment: Can't you just **mount** `\\FS001\shared\log` on `/data` ?

Comment: @MSalters that was the first thing I've tried but i get errors such as 'access denied' on shares as open to public as possible, and from what little information I could find on it, I get conflicting info if this is even possible. 

I tried various combinations of :
"docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=fs004,rw --opt device=:"/share" --name nfs"
but same issues. Hoping to get some more clues here...